# Testing GWT serialization

Tags: gwt, serialization, junit

I want to write a JUnit test to verify whether or not a particular object can be successfully serialized by the GWT RPC procedure.  How would I do this?  I'm using GWT 2.4 and JUnit 4.8.1.

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Have you upgraded to GWT 2.6 or 2.7?  It seems like the accepted answer doesn't work anymore.  Did you find a way to test in the latest GWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  It is

```
@Test
public void testObjSerializability() { 
    final Object obj = getObject();
    final HostedModeClientOracle hmco =new HostedModeClientOracle(); 
    final HasValues command = new ReturnCommand(); 
    final HasValuesCommandSink hvcs = new HasValuesCommandSink(command); 
    final CommandServerSerializationStreamWriter out = new CommandServerSerializationStreamWriter(hmco, hvcs); 
    try { 
        out.writeObject(obj); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        fail("Object couldn't be serialized:" + e.getMessage());            
    }
}
```

Comment: this test passes with this class:

    public class MyClass implements IsSerializable {
        private File file;
        public MyClass(String fileName) {
            this.file = new File(fileName);
        }
    }

although https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideSerializableTypes requires a no-arg constructor. what's wrong here?

Comment: As of GWT 2.6 or 2.7 `HostedModeClientOracle`, `HasValues`, `HasValuesCommandSink` and `CommandServerSerializationStreamWriter` have been removed.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer does not check for a no args constructor; the following does:

```
public static void checkGwtSerializability(Object o) throws RuntimeException {
    HostedModeClientOracle hmco = new HostedModeClientOracle();
    HasValues command = new ReturnCommand();
    HasValuesCommandSink hvcs = new HasValuesCommandSink(command);
    CommandServerSerializationStreamWriter out = new CommandServerSerializationStreamWriter(hmco, hvcs);

    try {
        out.writeObject(o);
    } catch (SerializationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Object not serializable: " + o + " Caused by: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    try {
        o.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Object not serializable: " + o + " Caused by: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This also fails to check if fields of the object have a no-arg constructor.

Comment: As of GWT 2.6 or 2.7 `HostedModeClientOracle`, `HasValues`, `HasValuesCommandSink` and `CommandServerSerializationStreamWriter` have been removed.